# Would the following question be more suitable for SuperUser or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, stackoverflow, site-rec

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041477/shared-resources-on-a-partitioning-multicore-board

I am finding it hard to ascertain whether the above question would be suitable for here or Stack Overflow.

I would appreciate some clarification, as I am trying to learn.

Comment: What is the actual question in that post?

Comment: where such a question belongs? the one I've linked

Comment: I was referring to the linked post ;) Another user also noticed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041477/shared-resources-on-a-partitioning-multicore-board#comment24636977_17041477

Comment: oh sorry! lol Yes I wondered about that also, but he is asking a question in a round-about way. I was reviewing it as a first user question and flagged it for SuperUsers and was not sure if this was the right thing to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really not sure what the user is trying to ask - and as such I'd actually vote to close as  Not a Real Question on Stack Overflow itself. At it's current state, it's definitely not for Super User and even if fixed to some shape, across the lines of

> how to share code across partitions

it isn't really on-topic for Super User

Comment: thank you Sathya, I didn't want to flag it as closed, as I thought it could be reworded perhaps, but mistakenly flagged it for this forum